# We also offer [what] for open source projects?

Tags: support, status-norepro, internet-explorer, site-faq

In the "May I promote here?" section of the FAQ there is an omission of some word;

> We also offer [special discounts? rates?] for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

What is it that StackExchange is offering?

(Confirmed on [Webapps.se](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion), [Prowebmasters.se](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion), & [cooking.se](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion))

---

Addendum: To amanaP's reply, I totally believe you but...

[image]

---

I thought this was a typographical error, looks like a bug. We are running IE 7.0(.5730.13)  in XP (SP3). What is odd is that my browser is rendering the "contact our sales team" link immediately preceding the link that isn't displaying correctly.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on FF8.0.1 (OS X 10.6.8).

Comment: Just upgraded my malware VM IE to 7 (Win XP). Can't reproduce. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Tr7bl.png

Comment: No-repro on FF8 and IE8 (!) on Win 7, 32-bit.

Comment: No repro in IE8 on XP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: see there]

> We also offer **free community promotion ads** for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

It is the same on all 3 sites (in Chrome).

In IE7: The promo box is mysteriously missing:

[image: where is it?]

But when I click on `May I promote here?` I see:

[image: clicked!]

Comment: Since the link is displaying correctly on your machine, this may be an IE7+XP issue. An addendum has been added to the question.

Comment: @mfg see my update

Answer (score 8):

Given the nature of the link text - "free community promotion ads" - and the fact that it selectively applied to that link and not the preceding one, my money is on this being the effect of some **ad-blocker or malware blocker**, not a bug in IE proper.